# Laravel 5: Join On with IN query

Tags: sql, laravel

I'm trying to do something like:

```
$results = $query->leftJoin('checklist_items', function($join) use ($days) {
    $join->on('users.id', '=', 'checklist_items.user_id')
        ->on('checklist_items.due_date', 'IN', $days);
})
    ->where('checklist_items.user_id', null)
    ->limit(10)
    ->get();
```

This is an example of the query I'm attempting to execute:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN checklist_items 
ON users.id = checklist_items.user_id 
AND checklist_items.due_date IN ('2015-07-09', '2015-07-10') 
WHERE checklist_items.user_id IS NULL
ORDER BY users.id
```

So this is a left outer join. In query builder, most of this is no problem. The problem is the fact that my AND line uses an IN query. If it were part of a WHERE clause I would use ->whereIn but since I need it in the Join clause, whereIn won't work and there is no orIn or some such.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you would need to use `DB::raw()` so it doesn't try to quote your days and wrap your days in parenthesis as well.  This should do the trick.

```
$days = '(\'2015-07-09\', \'2015-07-10\')';
$results = DB::table('users')->leftJoin('checklist_items', function($join) use ($days) {
    $join->on('users.id', '=', 'checklist_items.user_id')
        ->on('checklist_items.due_date', 'IN', DB::raw($days));
})
->where('checklist_items.user_id', null)
->limit(10)
->toSql();

echo $results;
```

Comment: Almost. This worked: `->on('checklist_items.due_date', 'IN', DB::raw('(\''. implode('\',\'', $days) .'\')'));`

Answer (score 4):

You can use `->whereIn()` within the `->leftJoin()` closure (Tested in Laravel 5.7.16):

```
$days = ['2015-07-09', '2015-07-10'];
$results = \DB::table('users')
    ->leftJoin('checklist_items', function($join) use ($days) {
        $join->on('users.id', '=', 'checklist_items.user_id')
            ->whereIn('checklist_items.due_date', $days);
    })
    ->where('checklist_items.user_id', null)
    ->orderby('users.id')
    ->get();
```

Output from `dd(\DB::getQueryLog();` produces your example query:

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "query" => "select * from `users` left join `checklist_items` on `users`.`id` = `checklist_items`.`user_id` and `checklist_items`.`due_date` in (?, ?) where `checklist_items`.`user_id` is null order by `users`.`id` asc ◀"
    "bindings" => array:2 [▼
      0 => "2015-07-09"
      1 => "2015-07-10"
    ]
    "time" => 6.97
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 2):

**This Query will Work**

```
$results = DB::table('users')
    ->join('checklist_items','checklist_items.user_id','=','users.id')
    ->whereIn('checklist_items.due_date',['2015-07-09', '2015-07-10'])
    ->whereNull('checklist_items.user_id')
    ->orderBy('users.id','asc')
```

Comment: That approach doesn't work because I'm not doing a where clause. I need to add to the join clause, not start a new where clause.

Answer (score 0):

For Laravel 7 and above use **whereIn** instead of **on** :

```
 $join->on('users.id', '=', 'checklist_items.user_id')
    ->whereIn('checklist_items.due_date',$days);
```